# Can't connect guest's adb to hardware device using usb passthrough Virtualbox

Tags: android, usb, adb, virtualbox, usb-debugging

I can't debug in a hardware device using Virtualbox USB passthrough.

I followed this tutorial (http://binglongx.com/2013/03/05/use-android-devices-for-guest-ubuntu-os-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7-host/) but no luck yet.

On the last few steps it says:

*Re-insert your device to a USB port.
You should see some message like “Installing VirtualBox USB device” on Windows Notification Area (for the first time).*

I was **not** able to see that message in Windows' notification area.

running **VBoxManage list usbhost** in cmd gives me this:

```
UUID:               6d3e69eb-37a3-456e-9d3f-0b5239208e1b
VendorId:           0x22b8 (22B8)
ProductId:          0x2e63 (2E63)
Revision:           2.40 (0240)
Port:               0
USB version/speed:  2/High
Manufacturer:       motorola
Product:            XT1058
SerialNumber:       04242xxxxx *(omitted)*
Address:            {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0032
Current State:      Busy
```

USB debugging is toggled on in the device so running **adb devices** on host lists the device properly.

I tried removing the Motorola's device driver from the host and reconnecting it but no luck yet.

```
Host machine: Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1
Guest machine: Ubuntu x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I tried setting the port forwarding for ADB inside the network section of VM configurations but it was not working for some reason.

I was only able to get it working by using this [AdbPortForward](https://bitbucket.org/chabernac/adbportforward/wiki/Home) tool.

It's very easy to setup, follow the link for a detailed description.